# Limiting decimal places in a directive

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive where I'm able to select the length of decimal places, and to accept **only** one comma or dot, but I'm facing problems to achieve the perfect regex.

My **code**:

```
var decimalLenght = 2;

ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
  if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
    var val = '';
  }
  var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/g, '');
  if (val !== clean) {
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
    ngModelCtrl.$render();
  }
  return clean;
});
```

Actually the regex isn't letting me insert dots or comma and also allows to type more than the limit of decimal places.

Comment: Your regex doesn't make sense. It deletes almost everything except numbers and/or dot + 1 to 2 numbers at the end. Show some before/after examples

Comment: It doenst makes sense because are not understanding the code, of course doesnt delete numbers..., i want to remove anything that isnt a number, dots or comas

Comment: Why didn't you use this directive? https://github.com/nitishkumarsingh13/Angularjs-Directive-Accept-Number-Only

Comment: It haves  bugs, i already tried it.

Comment: `i want to remove anything that isnt a number, dots or comas` - If you want to trim down to an accepted form of \d.\d, find the valid part and assign it to clean: if find `(\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?|[.,]\d{1,2})\d*$` clean = $1 else clean = ''. It would turn `asdfsdf88.12345` into `88.12` And you could take out the EOS `$` for some wiggle room.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have a very small issue in the regex (You had the start of string anchor (^) after the first "["), and you are not checking for comma...

```
/^[0-9]+([.,][0-9]{1,2})?$/g
```

From there, since it needs to be dynamic, it would be better to do

```
new RegExp("^[0-9]+([.,][0-9]{1," + decimalLength + "})?$", "g");
```

With those changes, and changing the check logic you should get something like

```
var decimalLenght = 2;

ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
        val = '';
    }

    var check = new RegExp("^[0-9]+([.,][0-9]{1," + decimalLength + "})?$","g");
    if (check.test(val)) {
        return val;
    } else {
         ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('');
         ngModelCtrl.$render();
         return '';
    }
});
```

Here is a fantastic tool I use to check my regexes http://www.regexr.com/. It has a very intuitive interface, and seems to handle escaping particularly well.

Comment: The problem is that will affetc the rest of the code example:var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/g, ''); I have this to be able to clean everything that isnt valid, this way the user can only insert valid values

Comment: @MarcoPereira The changes I have made should make it work for what you need

Comment: Its not working, when i keep typing in the input and when insert dot, it gets cleared.

Comment: @MarcoPereira You will have to decide how you want to manage error state, look at setting the ndModelCtrl into an error state rather than setting the view value

Comment: Here is a example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/890/
Check what im doint wrong please

Comment: In the second option/input, it lets you insert more than one dot

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [**directive**](https://github.com/nitishkumarsingh13/Angularjs-Directive-Accept-Number-Only) and set the input accordingly your requirements.

Here's a *snippet* to demonstrate it:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      $scope.options.push(i);
    }
  })
  .directive('nksOnlyNumber', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            var spiltArray = String(newValue).split("");

            if (attrs.allowNegative == "false") {
              if (spiltArray[0] == '-') {
                newValue = newValue.replace("-", "");
                ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
                ngModel.$render();
              }
            }

            if (attrs.allowDecimal == "false") {
              newValue = parseInt(newValue);
              ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
              ngModel.$render();
            }

            if (attrs.allowDecimal != "false") {
              if (attrs.decimalUpto) {
                var n = String(newValue).split(".");
                if (n[1]) {
                  var n2 = n[1].slice(0, attrs.decimalUpto);
                  newValue = [n[0], n2].join(".");
                  ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
                  ngModel.$render();
                }
              }
            }

            if (spiltArray.length === 0) return;
            if (spiltArray.length === 1 && (spiltArray[0] == '-' || spiltArray[0] === '.')) return;
            if (spiltArray.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;

            /*Check it is number or not.*/
            if (isNaN(newValue)) {
              ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue || '');
              ngModel.$render();
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="form">
    <label for="option">Decimal place: </label>
    <select id="option" ng-options="option for option in options" ng-model="option">
      <option value="">Select the length</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <label for="input">Input with decimals: </label>
    <input type="text" id="input" nks-only-number ng-model="input" decimal-upto="{{option}}" required>
    <br>
    <label for="input2">Input without decimals: </label>
    <input type="text" id="input2" nks-only-number ng-model="input2" allow-decimal="false">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But is giving me a error in the attrs.allowDecimal == "false", when i use for example <input type="text"  ng-model="mynumber" nks-only-number allow-decimal="false" />, it gives me a error $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Comment: I saw it now, but you said you want to limit the decimal places, right? Why do you need to desactivate the decimals?

Comment: because are the requirements from the project manager and client :S, they dont want the user to be able to insert any dots/commas, decimals, for less errors

Comment: Well, so I don't understand.. how you want to limit the decimals if "**they** *don't want he user to be able to insert any dots/commas, decimals, for less errors"*.?

Comment: forget what i say,sorry, continue, do you have a idea why is giving the error $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Comment: @MarcoPereira, check it now.

Comment: Is great, thanks a lot :-), sorry for one more last question and i dont botter you more lol, is it possible the user be able to instead instead a dot a comma also? Just for this 2 situations, comma or a dot.

Comment: Yes :S, , really sorry for this.

Comment: Found the strangest bug, if i put required in the input field, i cant delete the last number, it will always have one number and cant delete it, try to put required in the input, insert 2 numbers and than try to delete it.

Comment: Easy to solve. I changed the code: `if (newValue != oldValue) {` to `if(newValue) { `. Look it.

Comment: @MarcoPereira, by the way, just one question: why do you have 2 users asking the same thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362583/directive-error-rootscopeinfdig-infinite-digest-loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117297/discussion-between-marco-pereira-and-developer033).