# Directive error $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I downloaded a directive that receives only numbers and has some additional options; but, after running it I get a rootScope error in one of the options that is:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="mynumber" nks-only-number allow-decimal="false" />
```

I believe the false conditional is making this error appear, but I don't know why.

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/896/

Code:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .directive('nksOnlyNumber', function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'EA',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {   
               scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  var spiltArray = String(newValue).split("");

                  if(attrs.allowNegative == "false") {
                    if(spiltArray[0] == '-') {
                      newValue = newValue.replace("-", "");
                      ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
                      ngModel.$render();
                    }
                  }

                  if(attrs.allowDecimal == "false") {
                      newValue = parseInt(newValue);
                      ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
                      ngModel.$render();
                  }

                  if(attrs.allowDecimal != "false") {
                    if(attrs.decimalUpto) {
                       var n = String(newValue).split(".");
                       if(n[1]) {
                          var n2 = n[1].slice(0, attrs.decimalUpto);
                          newValue = [n[0], n2].join(".");
                          ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
                          ngModel.$render();
                       }
                    }
                  }


                  if (spiltArray.length === 0) return;
                  if (spiltArray.length === 1 && (spiltArray[0] == '-' || spiltArray[0] === '.' )) return;
                  if (spiltArray.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;

                    /*Check it is number or not.*/
                    if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                      ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue || '');
                      ngModel.$render();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
}());
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle isn't very similar to your code posted here...which is right?

Comment: Is the same, i just posted here to show the code directlly

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem, looking at your pasted code (not the different JSFiddle), is that `ngModel.$render()` gets called twice. If I delete it from either the `attrs.allowDecimal == false` conditional or the end `isNaN(newValue)` conditional, the code runs fine.

Since I'm not sure what your end goal is, I've neglected to actually rewrite your code. But, that solved the [infinite `$digest` loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) error.

Comment: I already tried it and still gives me the error, you can check this link i update above: http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/896/

Comment: @MBPP no worries. If you [remove all of that `splitArray` and `isNaN(newValue)` stuff at the end](http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/898/), it works fine. Not sure if that had a good use (it seems kind of repetitive at first glance, but I may be missing something)...